# Eclipse Juno, maven project not able to run on server

Tags: eclipse, maven

I upgraded to **Eclipse Juno**(for Java EE developers). I installed **Maven Integration for Eclipse** through marketplace.

Just to test, I created a web app using *maven-archetype-webapp*. I cannot run on server(There's no menu *Run On Server*). The same happens with another maven project which runs fine using **Eclipse Indigo**. A tried deleting *.settings*, *.classpath*, *.project* then re-importing the project but nothing. I was hoping so much on **Juno**!

Does anyone know a real solution to this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about installing the [m2e-wtp](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/) plugin and trying?  You would want to confirm that the maven project is of `war` packaging as well.

Comment: I can confirm that packaging is war. m2e-wtp is installed already( Maven Integration for Eclipse). And FYI, I'm creating a web app exactly as in the demo of m2e-wtp. The difference is that in the end I have no Run On Server menu. Thanks though

Comment: Actually, didn't know that m2e-wtp is a different thing. Just installed it and now seems to work fine. Thank you

Comment: I've had the same problem, and the deployment assembly section wasn't configured correctly for the project's preferences.

Answer (score 10):

May be Dynamic Web Module in Project Facet is not selected

Go to :- **Project > Properties > Project Facets > check Dynamic Web Module**

Comment: talk about the tool getting in the way... gah!

Answer (score 1):

Run on server is not a maven feature, it's a "classic eclipse" feature.

In order to run a maven project on a server you must adopt a plug-in (e.g a Jetty plug-in for your webapp) and the run the proper maven goal (e.g jetty-run).

Said this, you can run a web project on a server with `(right-click) > Run as > Run on server` if you have the proper runtime environment configured.

Comment: I use Tomcat, and so far didn't need a plugin to Run On Server.

Comment: There is a maven plug-in for Tomcat too [http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/].
Maven runs projects through goals configuration, not through deployment on a server like you should do in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling "**Dynamic Web Module**" in *Project Facets* may not help here in maven projects.

Because maven projects are structured differently (*target/sampleApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war*) than the normal **Dynamic Web Projects** (*WebContent/*).

So, If you use **Dynamic Web Module** manually, then eclipse will try to use "*WebContent*" directory structure as deployment directory for Application Server which won't be the case in maven projects.

Solution is to use **m2e-wtp** plugin to do the *deployment*.

If you installed **m2e-wtp** plugin, it'll *automatically* detect your maven project type & it'll show you the "**Run as Server**" option in "*Run as*" menu in "*Project*".